# Heroku App crashed (Error H10)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, deployment, heroku, crash

I have an app which runs on rails 3.2.2 and uses postgres, I've deployed it to my heroku server before and it worked great.

In my last deploymend I didn't see any bugs in the deploy description but when I visited the app I saw it was down.

So I ran

```
heroku logs --app my_app_name
```

and this is what I got:
https://gist.github.com/2935603

I have no idea what is the problem.

Thanks for caring!

Answer (score 1):

check http://status.heroku.com - the platform is currently having issues.

Comment: Awesome dude, you're right it wasn't related to me :)

Thanks!